# Ubuntu server 13.10: Installing and running Archipel from deb packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, remote-access

I am setting up a server to host virtual machines based on Ubuntu Saucy.

The decision was to use [Archipel](http://archipelproject.org/) for remote administration.

Installation of ejabber and Web Client UI went smoothly.

For the Agent, There are detailed [installation instructions](https://github.com/ArchipelProject/Archipel/wiki/Installation:-Agent) for on the web site.

However, there are deb packages available in the Ubuntu repositories.

```
$ apt-cache search archipel
archipel-agent-action-scheduler - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Action Scheduler)
archipel-agent-hypervisor-geolocalization - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Hypervisor Geolocalization)
archipel-agent-hypervisor-health - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Hypervisor Health)
archipel-agent-hypervisor-network - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Hypervisor Network)
archipel-agent-hypervisor-platformrequest - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Hypervisor Platformrequest)
archipel-agent-iphone-notification - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent iPhone Notification)
archipel-agent-virtualmachine-oomkiller - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Virtualmachine Oomkiller)
archipel-agent-virtualmachine-snapshoting - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Virtualmachine Snapshoting)
archipel-agent-virtualmachine-vnc - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Virtualmachine VNC)
archipel-agent-vmcasting - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Vmcasting)
archipel-agent-vmparking - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent Vmparking)
archipel-agent-xmppserver - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Agent XMPP Server)
archipel-core - Virtual Machine Orchestration (Core)
```

I wanted to installed those packages instead of building from source.

However the startup script (/etc/init.d/archipel) and config file (/etc/archipel/archipel.conf) are missing in those packages. The Archipel tools are also not available in the packages listed above.

How is Archipel Agent supposed to be installed with deb packages on Ubuntu Saucy?